# Plotly: plot bar chart in stock price chart

Tags: python, pandas, charts, plotly

I have a chart of the apple stock prices. I want to add a bar chart at the bottom of the chart to display some calculations. (something like a volume bar chart). I can plot both charts separately but not together..

If I run my code the error is

```
plotly.exceptions.PlotlyRequestError: Hi there! Accounts on the Community Plan cannot create folders.
To save this file on Plotly, please remove the folder in your filename path.
```

Like I need a plotly premium account. Is that necessary?

This is my code. In the first part I draw the stock charts and in the second part I draw the bar charts ("sentiment chart").

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF
from datetime import datetime


df = web.DataReader("aapl", 'yahoo', datetime(2010, 10, 1), datetime(2019, 1, 15))
fig = FF.create_candlestick(df.Open, df.High, df.Low, df.Close, dates=df.index)
py.plot(fig, filename='finance/aapl-candlestick', validate=False)

df = pd.read_csv('results_data_bar.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [
    go.Bar(
        x=df['Date'],
        y=df['count_sentiment_svm'],
        width= 0.8,
        marker=dict(
            color='rgb(0,100,0)',
            line=dict(
                color='rgb(100,100,100)',
                width=1.5,
            )
        )

    ),
    go.Bar(
        x=df['Date'],
        y=df['count_sentiment_svm_neg'],
        width= 0.8,
        marker=dict(
            color='rgb(100,0,0)',
            line=dict(
                color='rgb(100,100,100)',
                width=1.5,
            )
        )

    ),
]
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    title='Sentiment'
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# IPython notebook
# py.iplot(fig, filename='pandas-bar-chart-layout')

py.plot(data, filename='stacked-bar')
```

Comment: Ok, but now I have 2 seperate plots. I want them in the same..

Comment: I'd like to recommend my plotting library [finplot](https://pypi.org/project/finplot/), which is made for finance plotting and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to try using plotly in offline mode? Such as:

```
# import plotly in offline mode
import plotly.offline as py
# That's line needed if you use jupyter notebook (.ipynb):
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
# your data, traces, layout are here
# And plot after that (for jupyter notebook):
py.iplot(fig)
# Or just py.plot if using python scripts (.py):
py.plot(fig)
```

From official docs - [link](https://plot.ly/python/offline/#generating-offline-graphs-within-jupyter-notebook)